# How to set the number of digits in the ANSYS fluent console

Tags: fluent, ansys

Hello: I want to know how to set the number of digits in the fluent console.
The defaults are only 6 digits in the output screen, the "XYZ" residual and all the monitor value, and the report values. I have used the double-precision fluent, but it still can't output more digits.
Could you please give me some suggestions?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit a MWE first, for anyone to find an error/correction in it.